# Object #<Object> has no method 'attr' when scraping with Cheerio and NodeJS

Tags: jquery, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

While following a tutorial about web scraping in Node JS, I ran into this problem when running this script in the terminal:

```
Object #<Object> has no method 'attr'
```

Here's the script I'm using:

```
var request = require('request'),
    cheerio = require('cheerio'),
    urls = [];

request('http://www.reddit.com', function (err, resp, body) {
    if (!err && resp.statusCode == 200) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        $('a.title', '#siteTable').each(function() {
            var url = this.attr('href');
            urls.push(url)
        });

        console.log(urls);
    }
});
```

Any ideas on how to fix this script so it doesn't throw an error? Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scope object `this` is not a jQuery object by default.

```
var url = this.getAttribute("href");
// or
var url = $(this).attr("href");
```

Comment: Wouldn't `this.href` be fine?

Comment: @RUJordan probably, but the `href` property is different than the attribute.

Comment: Note that's it's Cheerio, do the psuedo node created from the passed in strings even have properties, or a getAttribute method ?